# DataFrame how to add in a column containing a multidimensional array

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array, apache-spark-sql

I am unsuccessfully trying to manipulate an array in a dataFrame. for example I would like to make an addition or get the max for each id.

MyJSON file is like:

```json
{
    "prices": [
        [
            1601759212851,
            0.1858011018283193
        ],
        [
            1601924861574,
            0.1858011018283193
        ],
        [
            1601971658854,
            0.1858011018283193
        ]
    ],
    "vol": [
        [
            1606930725994,
            351221.0671864218
        ]
    ],
    "id": "myId1"
}
{
    "prices": [
        [
            1606930723991,
            0.002319862805425766
        ]
    ],
    "vol": [
        [
            1606930723991,
            651491.0171818669
        ]
    ],
    "id": "myId2"
}
```

```scala
val tf = spark.read.json("myJsonFile")
val test = tf.select("prices") 

val test: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [prices: array<array<double>>]
test.map(_._2).sum
```

I am getting this error:

```
<console>:28: error: value _2 is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

I've tried an udf as:

```
val totalPrice = udf((xs: Seq[Row]) => xs.map(_.getAs[Double]("prices")).sum)
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways of doing this. The easiest way, as of Spark 3.0, is to use the `transform` function (which is analogous to `map`, working with `Column` elements) on your DataFrame:

```
df.select('id, array_max(transform('prices, x => x(1))).as("max_price")).show(false)
+-----+--------------------+
|id   |max_price           |
+-----+--------------------+
|myId1|0.1858011018283193  |
|myId2|0.002319862805425766|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Another way is to transform your `DataFrame` into a `DataSet`, in which case `map`, `filter`, etc. will behave as you expect because you are dealing with simple Scala types:

```
case class Result(id : String, maxPrice : Double)

val result = df.map{
     case org.apache.spark.sql.Row(id : String, prices : Seq[Seq[Double]], _) => Result(id, prices.map(_(1)).max)
     }

result.show
+-----+--------------------+
|   id|            maxPrice|
+-----+--------------------+
|myId1|  0.1858011018283193|
|myId2|0.002319862805425766|
+-----+--------------------+
```

If for whatever reason you can't use the `DataSet` and are on a 2.x version of Spark, you can `explode` the prices column and use other DF functions on the simpler arrays:

```
 df.select('id, explode('prices).as("prices")).groupBy('id).agg(max($"prices"(1)).as("max_price")).show
+-----+--------------------+
|   id|           max_price|
+-----+--------------------+
|myId1|  0.1858011018283193|
|myId2|0.002319862805425766|
+-----+--------------------+
```

UDFs are also an option, but discouraged. I'd encourage you to check out https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/24/working-with-nested-data-using-higher-order-functions-in-sql-on-databricks.html for a rundown of various ways to deal with nested arrays in Spark.